# get Last one month record in mysql

Tags: mysql

i want to get last month record from mysql.i am using like this.it will return last month and the last year records also.

```
enter code here
select pt_product_name,
purhis_measurement,
purhis_quantity,
purhis_return_qty,
purhis_actual_qty,
purhis_per_qty_price,
purhis_ledgerid,
purhis_invoice_no,
purhis_purchase_dt,
purhis_invoice_dt,
purhis_type_of_purchase,
purhis_mode_of_purchase
from purchasehis_tb as pur,product_tb as pt
where pt.pt_bt_branchid='BRA102451717858'
and pt.pt_productid=pur.purhis_pt_productid
and pur.purhis_updated_dt>subdate(curdate(),interval 1 month)
```

Comment: And what is the question again?

Comment: pur.purhis_updated_dt BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW();

Comment: i want to get last month record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try thiz :**

```
select pt_product_name,
purhis_measurement,
purhis_quantity,
purhis_return_qty,
purhis_actual_qty,
purhis_per_qty_price,
purhis_ledgerid,
purhis_invoice_no,
purhis_purchase_dt,
purhis_invoice_dt,
purhis_type_of_purchase,
purhis_mode_of_purchase
from purchasehis_tb as pur,product_tb as pt
where pt.pt_bt_branchid='BRA102451717858'
and pt.pt_productid=pur.purhis_pt_productid
and pur.purhis_updated_dt BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()
```

Comment: any one help me .i want to prepare yearly report and also monthly report

Comment: you need monthly and yearly report in thiz query itself or another query